# Submitting file to website using PHP?

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

Ok so i wanted to submit the image on the following website (http://newocr.com/) but i dont have the idea how to do it. I cant find anything on Google.

Here are the code i am using

```
$url = "http://newocr.com/";
$urlref = "http://newocr.com/";
$ch = curl_init();

$data_array["userfile"] =  $imgpath;
$data_array["url"]  =  '';
$data_array["1"] = 'eng';
$data_array["preview"] ='1';

  if(is_array($data_array))
    {
    # Convert data array into a query string (ie animal=dog&sport=baseball)
    foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) 
        {
        if(strlen(trim($value))>0)
            $temp_string[] = $key . "=" . urlencode($value);
        else
            $temp_string[] = $key;
        }
    $query_string = join('&', $temp_string);
    }

    if(isset($query_string))
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, FALSE); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $urlref);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$return = curl_exec($ch);

echo $return;
```

The $imgpath variable specifies where the file is stored on my harddisk but
the file doesn't upload from my harddisk to the website. But when i do the  same thing using a url of the file stored on my web host instead of file path on pc it works.

So can anyone tell me how to do that. How can I upload this file directly from my hard drive instead of using a URL?

Thanks

Comment: The `url` parameter expects a public URL that the remote server can access. Putting a filename there won't work, since the remote server can't download the file.

Comment: that was a typing mistake i corrected it please read it again

Answer (score 0):

Note: your entire foreach loop is pointless. curl will happily take an array for the POSTFIELDS opt and do all that urlbuilding/encoding for you automatically.

To get curl to do an upload, you have to TELL it you're passing in a file path:

```
$opts = array(
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'file' => '@/path/to/file/on/server'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $opts);
```

Note the `@` in the array - that's the hint to curl that it's a file path and you want it to be uploaded. Also note the total lack of looping/manual encoding/url building.

Also note that in more recent curl/php implementations, this has been upgraded to a dedicated [CURLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/class.curlfile.php) option.

Comment: ok can you tell how will i set the path it is in the same directory as the script

Comment: sorry, but if you can't figure out a file path, then you shouldn't be programming to start with.

Comment: actually i have just started i have not incountered any thing to do with file path that's why